# Why is there blood on the commander Krause's foot?

Tags: plot-explanation, greyhound

It seems that Krause's foot gets hurt - he changes from boots to slippers, there is blood on the floor and slippers (~1h 6m into the movie).

How did this happen?

Why didn't he receive first aid?

Comment: why downvotes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://screenrant.com/greyhound-movie-true-story-battle-atlantic-wwii-explained/):

> in one scene, it reveals Krause's feet are actually bleeding from wearing his shoes and pacing so much while he's captaining for hours on-end (before he slips into more comfortable footwear).